# Want to see only the chr variables (out of a list of chr and num variables) using str() function

Tags: r, string, chr

I am using the following to get a sense of which variables are char, num, etc, and it works fine but now I'd like to see only those variables that R classifies as chr. Is there a path to doing so?

```
str(mtvtn, list.len = ncol(mtvtn))
```

I tried the following as well to no avail.

```
str(mtvtn, list = is.character(mtvtn))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
library(dplyr)
mtvtn %>% 
   select(where(is.character)) %>% 
   str(.)
```

Comment: Thank you @Timnus this worked out great for me. Hadn't thought of using a where statement!

Answer (score 0):

You need to subset.

```
str(dat[sapply(dat, is.character)])
# 'data.frame': 54 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ wool   : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
#  $ tension: chr  "L" "L" "L" "L" ...
```

or

```
str(dat[sapply(dat, inherits, 'character')])
# 'data.frame': 54 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ wool   : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
#  $ tension: chr  "L" "L" "L" "L" ...
```

Second version has the advantage that `what` can be a vector

```
str(dat[sapply(dat, inherits, c('character', 'integer'))])
# 'data.frame': 54 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ breaks : int  26 30 54 25 70 52 51 26 67 18 ...
#  $ wool   : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
#  $ tension: chr  "L" "L" "L" "L" ...
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- type.convert(warpbreaks, as.is=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you too Jay.sf. This was also very effective. I'm working through understanding what is happening in the scripts you've provided. Hopefully that will make me more flexible with R too so thanks for the rabbit hole!

Comment: @uThandi Essentially, the `sapply(dat, is.character)` gives you a boolean vector `FALSE, TRUE, TRUE` that allows you to subset `dat`.